# OpenCV 2.1 Python Bindings Segfaulting

Tags: python, opencv, segmentation-fault

Hello I have a problem when grouping the OpenCV's functions in functions of my own and getting segmentation fault.

Even with code as simple as this

```
def acquire_imagen():
  capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM( 0 )
  img = cv.QueryFrame( capture )
  return img
img = acquire_image()
print img[0,0]
```

If I call the same instructions outside the function everything is ok. I have an Idea of what may be happening but not enough knowledge about python to prevent it. I think the object is being freed by the GC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the capture object from being garbage-collected, keep a reference to it in a variable until you no longer need the images. In your code: the "capture" variable cannot be a local variable of the function, but a variable outside the function. Or, if you want it to be initialized inside the function, return it along with the captured image, and store it in a variable after the call to the function:

```
def acquire_imagen():
  capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM( 0 )
  img = cv.QueryFrame( capture )
  return capture, img
capture, img = acquire_image()
print img[0,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the capture object cannot be freed before accessing images captured from it. Don't let the "capture" object be freed until the image is no longer accessed in your program.

Comment: But how do I prevent the GC collecting it?